# How to do I solve rule 8.7 MISRA-C?

Tags: c, misra

misra_c_2012_rule_8_7_violation

Function "cpvqResponse" has external linkage but is only used in one translation unit.

Comment: What have you tried? What research did you do? How do you think you can resolve it? From simple logic, you can make the presented statement not true, so you can: remove the function cpvqResponse, or change the linkage of the function, or use the function in more than one translation unit.

Comment: Declare the function as `static` in the file where it is defined/used.

Comment: Sharon, Does `cpvqResponse()` have a declaration in an include file? If not, make one.

Comment: Well, it is declared in include file.

Comment: Can you expand the question, to show the declaration, the definition and the usage (or at least a minimal equivalence example)?

Comment: @Andrew, Hey the function has to be used in another .c file. It is also included in the include file, that's why i'm struggling

Comment: See answer, with correct approach, below

Comment: Of course, you could interpret *referenced in* (in the Rule headline) to mean that it defined in one translation unit, and used in another, they are *referenced in* two TUs, and R.8.7 does not apply.

Answer (score 2):

This means that functions that aren't exposed outside one particular .c file but only used in that file must be declared `static`. Which is a perfectly sensible thing to do in all C programs, regardless of MISRA-C.

Comment: "internal api", right!

Comment: That is not fully correct. This rule also applies to functions you define in one file (e.g. XY_Init function in some driver) that is used in a different file. It's not always an option to move that function into the other file and make it static there.

Comment: @Gerhardh Defining functions in header files is problematic and causes problems with other MISRA rules. It should be avoided save for a few exceptions, where you must have small `static inline` functions etc.

Comment: I am not talking about headers. You implement some driver in file1.c, among other some driver_Init() function. This function initializes static objects inside that file1.c. If this function is only called from one other translation unit file2.c a MISRA warning for driver_init() is generated. You cannot make it static in file1.c and you cannot move to file2.c also.

Comment: @Gerhardh In most cases that is simply bad design and the correct fix is to move the function to the translation unit where it is used. I suppose with the exception of really big code where you need to split the driver across several .c files. Which in turn is a very rare scenario, since drivers tend to be compact but complex code.

Comment: It might not be the best design, but I would think, taking the content of lots of files that are logically independent, and putting them together into one huge file doesn't improve the situation.

Comment: @Gerhardh If they are logically independent you wouldn't make calls across those "independent" translation units, now would you? Besides, how do you even call a function in another translation unit without either using external linkage or defining the function in a header?

Comment: Lundin, It doesn't seem to work!

Comment: @SharonDeborah It works just fine.

Comment: @Lundin it has to included in include file no?

Comment: Using static throws an error.

Comment: @SharonDeborah "It doesn't seem to work. There is an error." Yeah don't tell _what_ doesn't work, what error you get or anything. Making a function `static` and understanding when and why you need to do that is basic stuff.

Comment: @Lundin, of course they are declared in headers. Your first comment mentioned defining them in headers, which is not the case. Have you never come across those "nice" frameworks where you get loads of `HAL_XY_Init` and `HAL_XY_Run` functions to handle all the periperals that are called from one function each. Calling them in `HAL_Init` / `HAL_Run` does not make an UART function related to DMA or ADC. And of course, as HAL_Init and HAL_Run are only called from one translation unit they also have to be moved there until all functions are in same file as `main`. Same for some app functions

Comment: @Gerhardh I'm not even sure what you are talking about. Defined != declared. In order to call a function which is just _declared_ in a header, it does not have internal linkage but external, and is therefore not relevant for this rule.

Comment: The rule is about external linkage. Your answer only fixes that warning if the function and the caller are already in the same file. But the ruls also covers more cases. My point is that squashing everything into one huge file and change to internal linkage is not an option in many cases.

Comment: @Gerhardh Still not following. The rule says "Functions and objects should not be defined with external linkage **if they are referenced in only one translation unit**". A translation unit is a .c file and all the headers it includes. So for a function declaration and definition to be used in multiple files but the same translation unit, the declaration and definition can only be either in the .c file or split across the .h and .c file.

Comment: Yes in theory you could put a function declaration in one header and the definition in another header and it would still be the same translation unit. But then MISRA compliance is the least of your problems since the whole program design is off.

Answer (score 1):

Putting together all the comments, I understand that your code is something like this:

**library.c**

```
void cpvqResponse( void )
{
    ...
}
```

**library.h**

```
extern void cpvqResponse( void );
```

**project.c**

```
   void main( void )
   {
       ...
       cpvqResponse();
       ...
   }
```

MISRA C:2012 Rule 8.7 is an Advisory Guideline, and aims to enhance the cohesion of, and reduce coupling between, your translation units.

As outlined in MISRA Compliance, there are times and places where the MISRA Guidelines may be inappropriate, and there are mechanisms in place.

As it is *Advisory*, possible mitigations are:

1. Move the code - possible if project code, but not if *adopted code*
2. Just ignore the Rule - this is **contrary** to MISRA Compliance
3. Disapply the Rule, with rationale, eg code modularity - this is often the **correct** approach

As I have said before, anyone who demands 100% MISRA Compliance, with no deviations (or disapplication) hasn't read, or understood, the guidance.

[See profile for affiliation]

--- **Edited to Add** ---

Of course, the primary purpose of this Rule is to catch local definitions with external linkage:

**myfile.c**

```
void myfunc( void );  // Only used internally, should be **static**

void myfunc( void )
{
   ...
}

void main( void )
{
   ...
   myfunc();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that's a great explanation.

Comment: MISRA-C aside, not using private encapsulation of local functions is something that any decent code review (and analyser tool) will point out. So it isn't as much a MISRA-C issue as a "write proper C" issue.